# passing string value in GCC comand using variable

Tags: shell, gcc

I need to pass String Value in GCC command using variable

something like below

```
gcc -Dname= '"abc"'
```

but this "abc" will come in soime variable like

```
Name1=abc
```

Kindly tell will this work

```
gcc -Dname= $Name1
```

Comment: This sounds like a shell question. Tag appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), [variable substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html) will work here.

```
$ Name1=abc
$ cat main.cpp
NAME
$ gcc -DNAME=\"$Name1\" -E main.cpp
"abc"
```

If you are using a different shell, i.e. zsh or fish, they should also contain info and man pages that tell you how variable substitution works for them.